# Smoothing path corners for use with SKAction followPath

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I am researching how best to round the corners on a `CGPathRef` so that when I call `SKAction` `-followPath:asOffset:orientToPath:duration:` my zombie smoothly animates round the corners rather than snapping by 90degs each time the little fellow takes a corner. There seem to be a few solutions on the web (and SO) about using Catmull-Rom splines which I am familiar with using from doing 3D Animation.

**My question:** is does anyone know of a simple way to add rounded corners, implementing Catmull-Rom seems a little over the top for what I need.

**Secondly:** if it does indeed need to be Catmull-Rom how easy.hard is it to get the resultant curve back into a `CGPathRef` so I can feed it into my `SKAction`?

**NB:** The path is generated by a simple A* implementation that stores a number of CGPoint [x,y] waypoints that I then want to use as a basis for my path. I don't want to use Bezier curves if possible as I want to keep the new path close to the tile centre line to avoid collidable objects. I also don't want to have to start calculating ctrl points for hulls when I am almost where I need to be with my initial path approximation.

[image]

```
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, [[[self pathArray] firstObject] position].x, [[[self pathArray] firstObject] position].y);
    [[self pathArray]enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if(idx != 0) {
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, [obj position].x, [obj position].y);
        }
    }];

    SKAction *pathAction = [SKAction followPath:path asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:[[self pathArray] count]/2];
    [[self zombie] runAction:pathAction];
```

Comment: You could try adding [arcs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextAddArc) when your path changes direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CGPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html) has a number of facilities for producing curves. You definitely don't need to implement Catmull-Rom or similar yourself. (And if `CGPath` isn't convenient for you, you can use the higher-level [`UIBezierPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) and get a `CGPathRef` out of it.)

For your application the simplest choice might be [`CGPathAddArcToPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000959-CH1g-CGPathAddArcToPoint). You'll need to extend your loop to determine when a turn instead of a straight line is needed, of course. Then instead of adding a line to the middle of the new square, add a line to its edge, then an arc whose `(x1, y1)` is the middle of the square, `(x2, y2)` is the edge the line should exit the square from, and `radius` is half the width of the square.